# Uploading files by ng-file-upload and paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I spent a lot of times with ng-file-upload and rails paperclip and stuck((. In standard view with new.html.erb paperclip works perfect. But with ng-file-upload browser returns an error.

```
Internal Server Error

bad content body
```

Or if I change upload in my controller:

```
afisha: {file: file} => to file: {file: file}
```

Routing Error:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [POST] "/public"
```

Here is my controller:

```
$scope.upload = function (file) {
           console.log(file);
            Upload.upload({
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/public',
                method: 'POST',
                afisha: {file: file}
            }).then(function (resp) {
                console.log('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + resp.data);
            }, function (resp) {
                console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
            }, function (evt) {
                var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
            });
        };
```

View:

```
<button class="btn" ngf-select="upload($file)">Upload on file select</button>
```

Rails controller:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :json
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

    def index
    respond_with Event.all
  end
  def show
    respond_with Event.find(params[:id])
  end
  def create
    @event = Event.create(event_params)
    @guests = guests_params[:guests].map { |guest|
      Guest.create(name: guest[:name], surname: guest[:surname], event: @event)
    }
    respond_with @event
  end

  def destroy
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    @event.destroy

  end

  def authenticate_user!
    if user_signed_in?
      super
    else
      redirect_to login_path
    end
  end

  private
  def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:name, :description, :date, :afisha)
  end
  def guests_params
    params.permit(guests: [:name, :surname])
  end
end
```

model:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :afisha, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :afisha, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/

  has_many :guests

  def as_json(options={})
    super(options.merge(include: :guests))
        .merge(:afisha => afisha.url)
  end

end
```

Comment: What is `afisha` is it a typo?

Comment: No, it is column in base in Events model.

Comment: This is Event's image

Comment: It has to be in this format `Upload.upload({..., data: {file: file},...})` not `Upload.upload({..., afisha: {file: file},...})`

Comment: Thank you, I solve my problem. It was two different POST actions, wrong format ng-file-upload and confusing permit parameters in rails controller.